# Laravel Multiple Joins with Counts (Not Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm going to convert this Eloquent query to DB query in Laravel.

```
$users = User::withCount("addresses", "cars")->get();
```

The above one is Eloquent and it's working well.
But I'd like to do this with DB query.

I tried to do as following but I couldn't get expected result.

```
$users = \DB::table("users")->join("addresses", "users.id", "=", "addresses.user_id")
->join("cars", "users.id", "=", "cars.user_id") 
->selectRaw("users.id, users.name, count(addresses.id) as addresses_count, count(cars.id) as cars_count")
->groupBy("users.id", "users.name")
->get();
```

The result value of `addresses_count` and `cars_count` were same and it was multiplied value of two.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A join will produce one row per combination of matched models for example for a user with car C1 and C2 and addresses A1, A2, A3you will get 6 rows: (U, C1, A1), (U, C1, A2), (U,C1,A3), (U, C2, A1), (U, C2, A2), (U, C2, A3). To "emulate" the eloquent behaviour you can consider doing subqueries or multiple queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to add `distinct` in `count` like:

```
$users = \DB::table("users")->join("addresses", "users.id", "=", "addresses.user_id")
->join("cars", "users.id", "=", "cars.user_id") 
->selectRaw("users.id, users.name, count(distinct addresses.id) as addresses_count, count(distinct cars.id) as cars_count")
->groupBy("users.id", "users.name")
->get();
```